# AngularJS: How to bind a model specified in the view (ng-bind) to a $resource available through an API?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to connect (in Angular, at the client) the same database object through its html view, to its equivalent instance through a json API.

I have a working api and $resource, and have a working view, I just can't figure out how to create the binding, so that updates to the view update the Angular model / $resource.

Specifically, I have an html view populated server side that contains an ngBind attribute:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-app="Posts">
  <div class="ng-scope" ng_controller="PostsCtrl">
    <span contenteditable="true" ng-bind="post.1.text">post.1.text value</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are several of these on the page with unique ids.For the purpose of the example, if it's easier to think of this as a form text field, then ignore 'contenteditable', an I'll deal with that part separately.

The format of that attribute is flexible, that's just how it is currently (i.e. post.1.text could be post_1_text, or split up entirely as needed.)

The resource factory looks like this (coffee script, but answers in js equally gratefully received!:

```
app = angular.module 'Posts', ['ngResource']

app.factory 'Post', ($resource) ->
  $resource('/api/posts/:id', {id: '@id'})

app.controller "PostsCtrl", @PostsCtrl = ($scope, Post) ->
  $scope.posts = Post.query()
```

which successfully populates a posts collection (not needed for this example, but shows the API is working).

So, what should ng-bind look like, and how to bind the controller to get updates to the view written back to the API?

(I know I could just use `ng_repeat: "post in posts"`, but just go with me that I really do want to do this. "It's complicated" :-)

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a jsfiddle that shows roughly what I'm trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QfVW/5/

...but i'd like the id to bind to the object key 'id' rather than to the index of the object in the array.

Comment: what's so complicated that it makes more sense to build the view first, then try to match view to model? You could certainly do it with directives and some element traversing to get indexing but it seems so backwards, hard to test and prone to error. A demo would help

Comment: User defined liquid templates. The content of the view is unknown, but I can inject ng-bind attributes to identify the resource(s) included. Thinking about it could even dynamically modify the js before it's sent to the client, but I'd rather not! A demo is doable, but I hope everything relevant is in the question.

Comment: `ng-bind` will automatically populate text ( not html). So if that's all you need...you should be able to create a matching convention between controller scope array and element by simply using `$index` if I'm understanding situation properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a fork of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drubarth/Ph8tU/) with three variations so that you can see different methods.

I used the simpler syntax for binding.  I think you'll find your code easier to read with the {{braces}}.

Your data is setup as an array, so you need to reference it by the index within the array.  In my revision of your original code I simply added the index.  Probably not that useful.

```
John is {{friends[0].name}} and has id {{friends[0].id}}
```

I the next addition to your code, I added scope variables in the js and assigned them to the index values so that you could use those variable names in the view.  Probably not the approach you'll use, but just to give you an idea of options.

```
Joy is {{friends[joy].name}} and has id {{friends[joy].id}}

$scope.joy = 1;    // in the javascript
```

Most likely you'll want to create a look-up function, which is the next addition you'll see.  Here I pass in the id of the friend I want to find and loop to find a match, then return the entire friend object. In the view I can then reference any of the friend properties.  The '9' could also be a variable name.

```
Peter is {{getFriend(9).name}} and has id {{getFriend(9).id}}

$scope.getFriend = function(fid) {

    angular.forEach($scope.friends, function(friend, key) {
        if (friend.id == fid) {
            found = friend;
        }
    });
    return found;
};
```

Does that help answer your question?  My original response should explain what's missing in order to update the model.

Comment: Thank you! I had hit on a solution that was a hybrid of your two solutions, iterating over the array, and exposing the keys as variables: `http://jsfiddle.net/2QfVW/9/` (using a for loop - didn't know about `angular.forEach`). But while it works with the static array, it didn't work with the `$resource` as that hadn't loaded when the iterator ran. Guess I'd need a callback, but didn't get that far... Yours finder works perfectly with the $resource! (had to add `var found` before the forEach). Seems you can't return early from `forEach`, would `for` be better? What advantage does forEach offer?

Comment: Meant to say, the reason for not using the braces is so the html still works without js. The js will add editing functionality (hence content editable in the original Q). Upvoting and selecting your answer as correct, but grateful for any additional pointers from my previous comment (or should I start a new Q?). Thanks again!

Comment: Also, should I edit the original question to reflect the more general case of finding object keys in an array?

Comment: You definitely have to use the success and fail callbacks with your $resource.  That one threw me for a while. Re the Angular.foreach, quite honestly I just use it because it's the Angular way.  There are posts that recommend against it if you are concerned about performance (appparently the for loop is fastest).  I'm not clear what you mean about the braces, but that's probably because I don't know what you have planned for your app.  You should update the original question, because it was only from your jsFiddle that I could understand what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, so if I'm off, please clarify.

I believe what you're missing is an event which you can use to trigger your update.  Perhaps you can explain more how the UI works.  Does the user click a button to submit the post?  Do you want it automatically submitted based on seconds?  Do you want it submitted after each change?  On blur?

Whatever the event/timer is, then you would use that in your controller to trigger the model save (or whatever you want to do with your model).  In that you would simply reference $scope.post (or whatever) from your view since two-way binding between the view and the controller is automatic in Angular (assuming you inject the scope module).  You shouldn't need to use the ng-bind nor the ng-scope in your view.

Hopefully I'm not totally misunderstanding your question.

Darryl

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it isn't the trigger that's causing me problems, but rather the binding. I need to bind to a specific elements in the html. I can add any attribute/value to those elements on the server side to aid identification, and/or add code on the client side to massage the binding, but this part eludes me. I should add I'm new to angular, and a novice at js.